# performance tuning on Eigen sparse matrix

Tags: performance, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

I've implemented something using `Eigen`'s `SparseMatrix`, basically it's something like,

```
SparseMatrix W;
...
W.row(i) += X.row(j);  // X is another SparseMatrix, both W and X are row major.
...
```

and I did some perf-profiling on the code via `google-pprof`, and I think the above code is problematic, see figure below,

**fig 1**

[image]

then **fig 2**

[image]

finally **fig 3**

[image]

looks like the `operator+=` brings in much memory-copy stuff.

I don't know much about the internals of `SparseMatrix` operations, but is there any recommended way to optimize the above code?

Comment: Does `W.row(i)` and `X.row(j)` have the same sparsity patterns?? If yes, then this could indeed be optimized.

Comment: @ggael, yes, they're supposed to be, at least the each row of `W` should cover whatever sparse rows in `X`, which means, in terms of sparsity patterns, each single row of `X` should be a subset of any row in `W`.

Comment: @ggael, if `W` is a dense matrix, the above `W.row(i) += X.row(j)` could still be optimized further? Also I wonder if eigen's `SparseMatrix` elem-wise addition is less performant than ordinary c++ impl using stl `hashmap` or vector?

Comment: @ggael, could you please give me some hint?

Comment: If W is a dense matrix (e.g., `MatrixXd`) then this should be fine. If W is a sparse matrix but you are sure that `W.row(i) += X.row(j)` can be done in-place without any reallocation/copies, then this could be optimized within Eigen itself by (1) extending the API to let Eigen knows and (2) writing the respective in-place evaluation code. Meanwhile, you could write your own inplace evaluation. I'll post an exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sparsity of X is a subset of the sparsity of W, then you can wrote your own function doing the addition in-place:

```
namespace Eigen {
template<typename Dst, typename Src>
void inplace_sparse_add(Dst &dst, const Src &src)
{
  EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT( ((internal::evaluator<Dst>::Flags&RowMajorBit) == (internal::evaluator<Src>::Flags&RowMajorBit)),
                      THE_STORAGE_ORDER_OF_BOTH_SIDES_MUST_MATCH);

  using internal::evaluator;
  evaluator<Dst> dst_eval(dst);
  evaluator<Src> src_eval(src);

  assert(dst.rows()==src.rows() && dst.cols()==src.cols());
  for (Index j=0; j<src.outerSize(); ++j)
  {
    typename evaluator<Dst>::InnerIterator dst_it(dst_eval, j);
    typename evaluator<Src>::InnerIterator src_it(src_eval, j);
    while(src_it)
    {
      while(dst_it && dst_it.index()!=src_it.index())
        ++dst_it;
      assert(dst_it);
      dst_it.valueRef() += src_it.value();
      ++src_it;
    }
  }
}
}
```

Here is a usage example:

```
int main()
{
  int n = 10;
  MatrixXd R = MatrixXd::Random(n,n);
  SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> A = R.sparseView(0.25,1), B = 0.5*R.sparseView(0.65,1);

  cout << A.toDense() << "\n\n" << B.toDense() << "\n\n";

  inplace_sparse_add(A, B);

  cout << A.toDense() << "\n\n";

  auto Ai = A.row(2);
  inplace_sparse_add(Ai, B.row(2));

  cout << A.toDense() << "\n\n";
}
```